# function that generates a list of all plane partitions of a given dimension

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, partitions

Is there a function in Mathematica that generates a list of all [plane partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_partition) of a certain dimension $n$? [This paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.tcs.2012.11.013) describes the algorithm, but I still find it a bit tricky to do it myself.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the [Wolfram MathWorld Plane Partition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PlanePartition.html) page has the algorithm implemented (select "[Download Wolfram Notebook](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/notebooks/Combinatorics/PlanePartition.nb)"):

```
<< Combinatorica`

coversQ[parent_, child_] :=
   And [ Length[parent] >= Length[child] ,
      Min[Take[ parent, Length@child] - child] >= 0]

planepartitionQ[par_] := 
   MatchQ[par, {{___Integer} ..}] && 
      If[Length[par] > 1, 
   And @@ MapThread[coversQ, {Drop[par, -1], Rest[par]}],
          True]

PlanePartitions[n_Integer] := Module[{l1, l2, l3, l4},
  l1 = z @@@ Partitions[n] ;
  l2 = l1 /. k_Integer /; (k > 1) :> w @@ Partitions[k];
  l3 = l2 /. z[x_w, y : (1 ...)] :> Thread[z[x, y], w] /. 
                  z[x__w] :> Outer[z, x] /. 
               z[x__w, y : (1 ...)] :> 
                  Outer[z, x, Sequence @@ ({y} /. 1 -> w[1])] /. 
    w -> Sequence;
  l4 = l3 /. 
     z[x___List, y : (1 ..)] :> z[x, Sequence @@ Transpose[{{y}}]] /. 
            z -> List;
  Cases[Union[l4], _?planepartitionQ]]
```

Can't speak to its validity or if it's precisely what you're looking for, and it relies on the outdated `Combinatorica` package, but it should be a great starting point for what you're after.

Comment: I ran a few tests, and it looks like Combinatorica is not required if you replace `Partitions[...]` with `IntegerPartitions[...]`.

Comment: That sounds right. Most of the functionality from the package has a built in replacement nowadays.